# System.Windows.Controls.Expander MFC equivalent

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Does anybody know an MFC equivalent of the WPF System.Windows.Controls.Expander?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct correlation. One option is to inherit `CGroupBox` and roll it up when the header is clicked. The more difficult aspect of mimicing WPF-style GUI is the layout engine. If you want any kind of fluid layout in MFC you'll have to use a 3rd-party library ([example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/resizabledialog.aspx)) or roll your own.